# Are there any differences if i create a new Sharepoint User Group from the site collection level or from the sub site level

Tags: 2013, permissions, administration, groups, site-settings

I am working on a sharepoint server 2013. and i am a bit confused on what is the right approach of creating new SharePoint user groups. now i have the following:-

1. Team site collection `http://servername/sites/HR`
2. sub-site of type team site collection `http://servername/sites/HR/Managers`

now i did the following 2 approaches for creating a new group for the sub-site:-

First Approach:-

1. Inside the site collection. i went to >> Site Settings >> Site Permission >> click on Create Group.
2. I enter the group name and the group owner.
3. click on create
4. then i went to the sub-site >> site settings >> Grant Permission >> select the new group.

Second Approach :-

1. i went directly to sub-site >> Site Settings >> Site Permission >> Create Group.
2. I enter the group name and the group owner.
3. click on create

now on both approaches the group will be added inside the site collection level and also inside the sub-site. now i thought using the second appraoch will add the group to the sub-site only (since i click on "Create Group" from the sub-site settings page), but seems using the second approach is similar to first appraoch where the new group will be added to the site collection level and also can be granted to other sub-sites.

so can anyone adivce if there are any differences between the 2 approaches , i am unaware of ?

Thanks

Comment: doesnot make any difference..you will not having the concept of sub site group..all groups are site groups only.

Comment: @PradeepKumar so internally both approaches will produce the exact same groups ?

Comment: yes both are same. only one group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you create them, groups only exist in one place, the site collection root. Creating them anywhere makes them available everywhere in the collection.

Comment: so internally both approaches will produce the exact same groups ?

Comment: Yes, both approaches will produce exact same groups

Comment: Correct. Both approaches achieve the same result.